# Can't compile multiple files for Arduino

Tags: c, makefile, arduino, avrdude

I'm having an issue with compiling code for Arduino if the code is in multiple files.  What I have been doing in the past is have a script concatenate the files in another directory and `make` the project there.  I would like to be able to compile directly from my build folder without having to jump through hoops of making sure everything is defined in the right order, etc.

I'm using `avrdude` to compile from Linux command line, because the Arduino IDE doesn't work very well with my window manager.  When I make with multiple files (with appropriate `#include` statements, I get errors of the following nature, but for all of my methods and variables.

```
./../lib/motor.ino:3:21: error: redefinition of ‘const long unsigned int MOVE_DELAY’
./../lib/motor.ino:3:21: error: ‘const long unsigned int MOVE_DELAY’ previously defined here
```

The only other place that `MOVE_DELAY` is used is inside the `void loop()` function, and it doesn't redefine it there.  The code also compiles fine if concatenate it into one file and run `make` in that directory, but not if they are in separate files with includes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is solvable by declaring the objects with the "extern" prefix or external. For example. I often use the SdFat library, in which it is included in both my main sketch and instanced in other libraries.

```
/**
 * \file test.ino
 */
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <foo.h>
SdFat sd;
...
```

Where I also use the same object in other libraries, such as foo.h.

```
/**
 * \file foo.h
 */
#include <SdFat.h>
extern SdFat sd;
...
```

If it was not for the prefix of "extern" it would error like yours, as "sd" can not exist twice. Where the extern prefix tells the linker don't make a new instantiation, rather link to the externally instance elsewhere.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, unfortunately.  My code only has one declaration of the variables that are giving this error.  It also gives me the error on a `struct` that appears only once in the code.  Moreover, when notifying me where the field was previously defined, it gives me the same line that it just said was problematic.

Comment: Taking the compiler at face value; MOVE_DELAY delay is defined twice. The question is; How? If not the above, then somewhere. I would expect that this file is being called recursively, if it were a .H or .CPP. Except I see that it is a .INO. So either "MOVE_DELAY" exists globally or in another library. I am able to compile a test with "const long unsigned int MOVE_DELAY = 0;" in the INO, so it does not exist globally.

Comment: I take note of your comment "I'm using avrdude to compile", I think you mean avr-gcc, as avrdude is not a compiler but a utility to upload files. So I believe the problem is related to your make. Which could be linking in the INO twice.